# Check logfile size and alert if not updated in 30 minutes

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I believe this is possible to do but not being an expert on Linux and shell scripting.

I believe I can use the watcher command to check the logfile directory but I am not sure how I would set it up to send an email alert to advise that this logfile directory hasn't been updated in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `crontab` would be of use to you:

Perform an action every minute:

```
echo "* * * * * touch $(pwd)/washere1" | crontab
```

Perform an action every 30 minutes:

```
echo "30 * * * * touch $(pwd)/washere2" | crontab
```

Check for the existence of the file "washere1" or "washere2" to verify that the command worked.